# Coveo diagnostics error: Invalid JSON primitive

Tags: coveo

Fresh install of Sitecore 8.1 update 3 with July 2016 Coveo release.

[image]

```
Invalid JSON primitive: .  Search for information on search.coveo.com
Hide details
 System.ArgumentException: Invalid JSON primitive: .
   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializePrimitiveObject()
   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializeInternal(Int32 depth)
   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.BasicDeserialize(String input, Int32 depthLimit, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(JavaScriptSerializer serializer, String input, Type type, Int32 depthLimit)
   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize[T](String input)
   at Coveo.Framework.Utils.JsonSerializer.DeserializeObjectFromString[T](String p_String)
   at Coveo.SearchServiceProvider.Rest.ResponseParser.ParseQueryResults(String p_JsonResponse)
   at Coveo.SearchServiceProvider.Rest.ClientSessionWrapper.ExecuteQuery(QueryParams p_QueryParams)
   at Coveo.SearchProvider.Applications.OnPremiseStateVerifier.VerifySearchService()
   at Coveo.SearchProvider.Applications.OnPremiseStateVerifier.<>c__DisplayClass14.<GetSearchServiceState>b__13()
   at Coveo.SearchProvider.Applications.BaseVerifier.VerifyComponent(Func`1 p_VerifyMethod, String p_ComponentName)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

wooot! solved my own issue. The CES certificate - cert-iis.p12 was not valid. Once I replaced this with the valid certificate, everything worked.

I wish the error was a bit more informative.